# How to do localization in Django based on UserProfile

Tags: django, localization

I want to do localization in Django based on the country code / locale set in users UserProfile instead of using whatever the browser/session/webserver thinks is the locale.

Is there a way to do this in django templates?

e.g how to change the behaviour of

```
{% load l10n %}
{{ value|time|localize }}
```

so that it formats the date based on what's stored in the profile, not based on some request context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django provides [LocaleMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware) that does most of what you are after:

> Enables language selection based on data from the request. It
>   customizes content for each user. See the internationalization
>   documentation.

The method it uses to guess the language is the same that is used by the translation machinery; that is it looks for a `django_language` variable in the session, if that exists and is a valid language, it will set that language for the request. See [how django discovers language preference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference).

Once you enable `LocaleMiddleware` and set `django_language` from the user's profile at your login view everything should work.

Comment: How do I run code after login if I use `contrib.auth.views.login`?

Comment: Not really related to this question, but you should listen for the [`user_logged_in` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_in) (only on django 1.3+)